# Sprite images in HTML, are they loaded before anything is shown?

Tags: html, css, image, css-sprites

If I have an image containing sprites:
http://www.starka.se/wp-content/themes/starka/images/sprites.png

Using these sprites on the website, will they show as that part of the sprites.png is loaded or will they only show until after the entire sprites.png has been loaded?

Let's say I'm on a connection so slow that this would be noticable...

Another way to clarify:
Would the STARKA text (which is at the top of the .png) show on the website before the social icons (which are a bit further down) or would they both show at the same time AFTER sprites.png is entirely loaded?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Yahoo](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) : It depends on where you put your Stylesheets. Depending on browser, the content will only show when all graphic elements related to this content are loaded. So you might think "It doesn't make any difference! ". So using or not using sprites doesn't make any difference, but only in HIGH SPEED connections.

But the thing is, using sprites reduces significantly the time a page needs to load. So "STARKA" might show before the social icons ON VERY VERY SLOW connections.

After visiting your website and seeing how many differents images you have, looking forward to use sprites won't be a loss of time ! It won't solve the problem for people using 56K, but it might still improve your website for many people :)

Comment: Did you just say 56K... in 2014?